# Merge function doesn't have output for all FCs, It has just first FC

Tags: arcpy

[image: Output details from tool]The attached file is my script for merging different FCs as they get dissolve and join by the input FC. I don’t know why the output for merge does not include all FCs.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
gdbname=arcpy.ListWorkspaces()
for gdb_Name in gdbname:
  env.workspace = gdb_Name
  for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
  hh=fc
  gg=arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, 'in_memory', '{}'.format(fc) )
  kk=arcpy.Dissolve_management(fc,gg,"Route_Type","","","")
  arcpy.JoinField_management (kk,"Route_Type",hh,"Route_Type",'#')

fClasses = []   #initialize array to hold feature classes
fClasses.append(gg)
arcpy.Merge_management(fClasses, "Merged")
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fClasses, output, '#' )
```

Comment: Move fClasses.append inside loop

Comment: I think it would help potential answerers, if you could take the 2-minute [Tour] to become more familiar with [framing good questions](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question) for GIS SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the changes you need to make for what I *think* you are trying to do. The script, with comments, is below, in case I'm not being clear (and for the sake of other readers).

1. Create your empty fClasses list at the top of your workspace loop, before you start looping through your feature classes. You are only getting one FC in the merged FC because you are re-creating the empty list with each iteration of the loop.
2. Your indenting was a little out of wack for the for loop.
3. Also, the conversion you are using is for single feature classes. You want to use arcpy.FeatureClassTo*Geodatabase*_conversion to make copies of your list of feature classes at the end of your script.

   ```
   import arcpy, os
   from arcpy import env
   arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
   env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # Workspace parameter
   output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # Workspace parameter
   gdbname=arcpy.ListWorkspaces()
   for gdb_Name in gdbname: # Iterate through workspaces
       env.workspace = gdb_Name
       fClasses = [] # Initialize list to hold feature classes
       for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(): # Iterate through FC's in each workspace
           hh=fc
           # Make copy of original FC in output workspace - interesting way to create an output path!
           gg=arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, 'in_memory', '{}'.format(fc) )
           kk=arcpy.Dissolve_management(fc,gg,"Route_Type","","","")
           arcpy.JoinField_management (kk,"Route_Type",hh,"Route_Type",'#')
           # Append modified FC to list
           fClasses.append(kk)
       # Create merged FC in this workspace
       arcpy.Merge_management(fClasses, "Merged")
       # Make copies of inidividual updated FC's in output workspace
       arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(fClasses, output)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for response, but I got this error when I ran the script:      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Script for FC to Single GDB - Dissolve and meregd By Route Type 3333.py", line 25, in <module>
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fClasses, output, '#' )
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1789, in FeatureClassToFeatureClass
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool

Failed to execute (GrabFeatureClasses).

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake and fixed my response. Please check it out (last line of code).

Comment: No, I got posted error when I used edited script from the previous post. It was about last line

Comment: The error message indicates that you used FeatureClassToFeatureClass instead of FeatureClassToGeodatabase--that was my fix. The first is if you are converting only one feature class; the last is if you are converting one or more feature classes (which you are). You can't feed FeatureClassToFeatureClass a list of multiple feature classes.

Comment: Thanks, It works but, there is a problem. It creates Merged FC as separated FC for each entry and all has same shape corresponded  to last input (FC).

Comment: The script try to read FC from multi GDBs and move all FCs To a single GDB along with applying Dissolve and Join, then Merge to the same defined GDB.

Comment: Sorry, one more edit. I worked too fast and made a couple of typos. The above edited script should work. This is assuming you want the data where the script comments say it is putting everything.  Also, make sure you are appending the updated FC to the list, not the original one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37966/discussion-between-koush-and-rhb).

Comment: As you can see I can't still get a single file called Merge and all entry Fcs has Merge file related to it with same FCs shape file. (please refer to the question)

Comment: If you only want one output file, you need to 1) Initialize the fClasses list outside of ALL of the loops, and 2) move the last two operations--the Merge and the FeatureClassToGeodatabase--outside ALL of the loops. Also, since you are switching workspaces, you need to make sure your list in fClasses includes entire paths.  This would actually be easier with da.Walk. You might want to check that out. Sorry I was not available for chat yesterday.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Yes, I figure it out this and the tool is responding correct. Thanks again for your comments and help.